# Is {x : ϕ(x)} a set with ϕ(x) being the property: ∀y (x ∈ y)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, separation-axioms

The property  ∀y (x ∈ y) contradicts the axiom of regularity since x ∈  x is not true for any non-empty set x.
Does this mean that {x : ϕ(x)} = $\emptyset$ which is a set or because it violates an axiom does that mean it is not a set?

Comment: Since $\phi(x)$ is false for all $x$, you are right: $\{x : \phi(x)\}$ is the empty set.

Comment: A property should be looked at as something that splits the universe of sets into those that have the property and those that have not. They do not "contradict" axioms, but sets can exist that do not have the property because of some axiom. Here that is the case for all sets.

Comment: By the way, $x\in x$ is false for $x=\emptyset$ as well.

Answer (score 2):

In ZF $\mathbb\{x\mid \forall y(x\in y)\}$ is a set and - as you noticed - it is the empty set.

Actually we can prove for some set $a$ that $\mathbb\{x\mid \forall y(x\in y)\}=\mathbb\{x\in a\mid \forall y(x\in y)\}$ and then the axiom scheme of separation ensures us that we are dealing with a set.

Answer (score 0):

The former.   The predicate is false because of the axiom, but it does not violate any axiom to build a set with a false constructor.   You just build the emptyset.